# Can't open Garmin gdb file on Ubuntu-mate 22.04 and QGIS 3.26

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu-mate 22.04 and QGIS 3.26 on a new PC. Now, I can't open my old Garmin *.gdb files. I have no problem opening them on Windows 10, though. And I find no problem opening them on my older installations of Ubuntu and older versions of QGIS. I tried installing QGIS 3.22, but still, I can't open them. It seems the problem is in Ubuntu.

What may be causing the error?

Comment: Sorry, I just found the answer. Sure enough, the problem is in Ubuntu. I forgot to install gpsbabel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS needs gpsbabel installed in Ubuntu. This solved my problem.